# GQL IN operator error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I encounter an appengine error from a GQL query with "IN"  operator. my query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE rating >= 0.0 AND cat = 1 AND pid IN(44,14)
```

the error message is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\ApplicationError' with message 'Encountered "IN" at line 1, column 84.
Was expecting one of:
    "contains" ...
    "has" ...
    "is" ...
    "=" ...
    "<" ...
    "<=" ...
    ">" ...
    ">=" ...
    "." ...
    "(" ...
    ' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php:53
```

I put my query in datastore admin console It works without any error and showed the exactly result.
What's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused about what the IN operator does. It can not do what you want.

Please read the docs on cloud datastore https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference

`Notice that the operator = is another name for the IN and CONTAINS operators. For example, <value> = <property-name> is the same as <value> IN <property-name>, and <property-name> = <value> is the same as <property-name> CONTAINS <value>. Also <property-name> IS NULL is the same as <property-name> = NULL.`

Comment: GQL doesn't support for OR operator and supports for IN operator differently. How can i transform a SQL command with IN operator into GQL? Otherwise, I should divide into several simple GQL select operation to get what I want?

Comment: Your options are perform 2 queries and merge the results after, or look at how you can restructure the PID property for instance maybe a range. Without knowing the datastructure and what the intent is its difficult to suggest strategies.